# How can i import data to a table from another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, drop-down-menu

I want to make an aplication of an movie db. so i have a table with movies (title genre,director, etc) and a table with directors. so i want when i create a new entry for movie  to have a dropdownlist to enter from the existing directors.

Comment: Where you want the other table in this scenario?

Comment: both tables are in my application. i also can modify director table on  another tab, but it will not have any dropdownlist ar anything special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will need to have 2 queries - 1 for retrieving your movies and one for inserting a movie. Since you are using an ORM (in your case Entity Framework) you will not have to write the queries on hand but you will have to use their API to do the job.

Here is an example:

```
MovieModel model = new MovieModel();
        List<Directors> directors = model.Directors.ToList();
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.Name = "Sample";
        movie.Id = 1;
        movie.Director = directors.First(x => x.Id = 1);
        model.AddObject(movie);
        model.SaveChanges();
```

In that example the `MovieModel` is your Entity Framework context and the list of directors is the collection you need to bind to your combo box.

Note that the directors.First(x=>x.Id=1); needs to be replaced with combobox.SelectedItem for your code.
Hope that helps.